# Sending updates to the server once the HTML player stops playing video

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, ajax

I am making a small purpose HTML5 video player using the concept of Video.js.

1. My python script executes the HTML code to play the video once it receives the URL from the server.
2. Once the video is completed it needs to send updates back to the server about the completion of the video and request for another video URL.

How can I implement the HTML code to send completion of video to my python script  which can further send it to the server?

Comment: document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN Media events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) You will see list of events for [HTMLMediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement). The one that might interest you is the `ended` event. Now you can use that like

```
var video = document.getElementById("videoTagId");
video.addEventListener("ended", function() {
  // Do ajax request to server here
});
```